# php does not add data to session variable

Tags: php, forms, session

I'm having trouble adding data to a session. I'm making a  small game where the user has to click on 2 buttons. If the game says click right, and the user clicks the right button it should add 1 to the score saved in the session else subtract 1.

The issue i'm running into is not passing data, but evaluating the answer submitted and the correct answer. I've tried multiple ways and with var_dumps I'm not getting any further, it shows me the answer and what the user submitted. At first I tried setting a variable to the post data and use that for checking but then i used a variable with a string with no result cause the score still remains 0.

game2.php:

```
 <?php 

 if (isset($_SESSION['antwoord2'])) {

           $antwoord1=$_SESSION['antwoord2'];
}
else {

           echo "geen waarde gevonden voor antwoord";
}

/*---------------------------------*/
/*      USER RESPONSE              */

if (isset($_POST['links1'])) {

$user_response1=$_POST['links1'];
$usr_antwoord = "links";

} else if (isset($_POST['rechts1'])) {

$user_response1=$_POST['rechts1'];
$usr_antwoord = "rechts";

} else {
echo "geen antwoord gegeven door gebruiker";
}
/*-------------------------------*/
/* SCORE CHECK                  */
$score=$_SESSION['score'];

/*-------------------------------*/
/* ANTWOORD CHECK                */

if($antwoord1 == $usr_antwoord) {
$score = $score + 1;

}
else {
$score = $score - 1;
}

?>
```

Var dump of the session with an echo variable `$usr_response1` results into something like this(when form data is submitted):

```
array(3) { ["score"]=> int(0) ["antwoord2"]=> string(6) "rechts" } 
USER INPUT : rechts
```

Comment: As always, do you have `session_start()`?

Comment: Yes, i did not show the full page code cause it would be too long for this page and thus unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand what you are trying to do, which is increase $_SESSION['score'] when the user clicked the correct button.

From what I see from your code, there is no area where you actually set $_SESSION['score'] to anything.

Expecting something like the following in that block of code

```
/*-------------------------------*/
/* ANTWOORD CHECK                */

if($antwoord1 == $usr_antwoord) {
  $_SESSION['score'] = $score + 1;
}
  else {
  $_SESSION['score'] = $score - 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not use `session_start()` at the first line of php script, you will not mantein any variables in the session